# Does 'soweit' mean anything other than 'as far as'?

Tags: meaning, translation

I [came across](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/zukunftskommission-landwirtschaft-ein-bisschen-tierwohl-16942017.html) this use of **soweit**:

> Beinahe ebenso lange wird es dauern, bis die Kommission ihre
> Empfehlungen abgeben wird: Im Frühsommer 2021 soll es **soweit** sein –
> dann, wenn mutmaßlich kaum noch etwas umgesetzt wird, der
> Bundestagswahlkampf in die heiße Phase geht.

I thought *soweit* is used in situations like *soweit ich sehe* / *soweit ich weiss*, etc. That doesn't make sense here. What would be the right translation in this case?

Comment: It should be "... soll es **so weit** sein ...". But the FAZ doesn't follow the official Orthography and uses its own.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Im Frühsommer 2021 soll es **soweit** sein...

That means, that the commission's recommendation will coming in early sommer 2021. "Soweit" references here to that point, when the commission's recommendation is coming (*in the early sommer 2020*). "Soweit" means here to a work progres, that will be finished at this point (*it should be ready in early sommer 2021*).